# Is a separate closure instance created for each nested function?

Tags: javascript

Apologies if my terminology is a little off... When a one function wraps another and a closure is created, is a new instance of the closure ("space in memory"?) created each time the outer function is called?

From my code here I believe the answer to be yes:

```
(function(){
  var ob = {}, names=['one', 'two'], i=0;

  var outer = function(val){

    ob[names[i++]] = function(){
      return val;
    };

  };

  outer(3);
  outer(999);

  console.log(ob.one());
  console.log(ob.two());
})();
```

Given that the result is

```
3
999
```

rather than

```
999
999
```

it appears as if `ob.one` points to a different closure instance to `ob.two` -each with its own value for `val`.

Is it more than my terminology that's confused?

Answer (score 3):

> Is a seperate closure instance created for each nested function?

yes, this is a desirable feature

An even more desirable feature would be block-level scoping, which javascript does not have. In fact, it is necessary to abuse nested functions in order to do nested `for`-loops in javascript, or else the variable binding will be mutated behind your back (e.g. if you hand it off to a callback, which you yourself demonstrate; just imagine the functions you're defining are, for example, onClick handlers for different elements; you will **want** the binding to be different).

Of course if you didn't like this feature, you could always use variables you define in an outer scope, such as you also do. =)

Answer (score 0):

It would have been better if `ob` had been called `inner`, but anyway...

> ...is a new instance of the closure ("space in memory"?) created each time the outer function is called?

Yes and no. The function assigned to *outer* has a closure to the activation/variable object of the outer anonymous function. When *outer* is called, that object is placed on its scope chain and is used for identifier resolution. This is the same object each time (ECMA-262 doesn't say how this is to be done, but for all intents and purposes it's the same object).

The function assigned to `ob[names[i++]]` has a closure to the instance of the activation/variable object created when *outer* was called and assigned the function. So each time *outer* is called, a new activation/variable object is created and each *ob[..]* function has a closure to a different *outer* activation/variable object but the same anonymous function activation/variable object.

I hope that makes sense.

> Given that the result is
>
> 3 999
>
> rather than
>
> 999 999
>
> it appears as if ob.one points to a
>   different closure instance to ob.two
>   -each with its own value for val.

Both functions have the same anonymous function activation/variable object on their scope chain, so "share" a closure to *obj*, *names*, and *i*. But each as a unique instance of an *outer* activation/variable object on their scope chain so *val* will resolve to the same property name but on different objects (i.e. they don't share the same *val* property).

Maybe the following diagram of the scope chains makes sense:

```
ob.one -> outerA -> anonymous fn -> global
ob.two -> outerB -> anonymous fn -> global
```

So *ob.one* and *ob.two* have an *outer* instance on their scope chain, but they are different instances. They have the same anonymous function and global objects on their scope chains.